# Something wrong with scipy.stats.lognorm.fit()

Tags: python, scipy

Can anyone help me this is literally my first question. I usually tried to find similar question before asking one, but this problem bugs me so much, and I really think something is wrong with the scipy lib.

For example, if you create a sequence of lognormal random variables:

```
from scipy.stats import lognorm
rvs = lognorm.rvs(size = 1000, s = 0.75, loc = 25, scale = 3)
```

If you want to fit this distribution, you might want to use:

```
args = lognorm.fit(rvs, s = 0.75)
```

But it shows error, saying no keyword for 's'. This is really bugging me, if you read the manual: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html#scipy.stats.lognorm it should be right

Then if you do something like:

```
args = lognorm.fit(rvs, loc = 25, scale = 3)
```

it works! and then if you try something like:

```
param = (25,3)
args = lognorm.fit(rvs, *param)
```

then another error. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

From the [lognorm docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html#scipy.stats.lognorm),

> As an instance of the rv_continuous class, lognorm object inherits
>   from it a collection of generic methods.

I.e. the `fit` method is inherited from `rv_continuous`

If look at the [docs for rv_continuous](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous) you will see that the `fit` method doesn't have an argument called `s`. See here for docs for the [fit method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit).

As your exmaple shows, this is plainly the case.

The docs for `lognorm` are at best misleading. I have reported the issue [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/12224)

Comment: The manual for lognorm does have a fit method with an argument 's'. Besides, it is the shape factor for lognorm so it doesn't make sense that it does not accept 's' as an argument.

Comment: I have amended my answer to address your comment